# download all images on the page with WGET

Tags: image, download, wget

I'm trying to download all the images that appear on the page with WGET, it seems that eveything is fine but the command is actually downloading only the first 6 images, and no more. I can't figure out why.

The command i used:

```
wget -nd -r -P . -A jpeg,jpg http://www.edpeers.com/2013/weddings/umbria-wedding-photographer/
```

It's downloading only the first 6 images relevant of the page and all other stuff that i don't need, look at the page, any idea why it's only getting the first 6 relevant images?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your command and it started downloading all images, Do you still have this problem? maybe the server was slow

Comment: If you notice, the image files listed in the page are all starting with aa_umbria*, my command instead after downloading the first 6 images starting like that, it downloads all other images, unrelated to the current page.

Comment: The use of `-r` is not right that would be 5 levels of recursion. What you want is `-p` (small p) see: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=wget+-nd+-r+-P+.+-A+jpeg%2Cjpg+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.edpeers.com%2F

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is, that there are only 6 jpegs on that site, all others are gifs, example:

```
<img src="http://www.edpeers.com/wp-content/themes/prophoto5/images/blank.gif"
 data-lazyload-src="http://www.edpeers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/aa_umbria-italy-wedding_075.jpg"
 class="alignnone size-full wp-image-12934 aligncenter" width="666" height="444"
 alt="Umbria wedding photographer" title="Umbria wedding photographer" /
```

data-lazyload-src is a jquery plugin, which wouldn't download the jpegs, see http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Try `-p` instead of `-r`

```
wget -nd -p -P . -A jpeg,jpg http://www.edpeers.com/2013/weddings/umbria-wedding-photographer/
```

see [http://explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=wget%20-nd%20-p%20-P%20.%20-A%20jpeg%2Cjpg%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.edpeers.com%2F2013%2Fweddings%2Fumbria-wedding-photographer%2F):

```
-p
--page-requisites
    This option causes Wget to download all the files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML
    page.  This includes such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.
```

Comment: I tried your command but it downloads only 3 images, i think it's because of that lazyload plugin that changes the src attribute to data-src and wget does not recognize what to download, could it be?

Comment: the above comment is most likely the correct answer

Comment: If you want to download all data-lazyload-src images, you would need some parsing of the page with `sed s/data-lazyload-src/src/g`